# cannot downgrade from ionic2 version to ionic1 version

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

At first, I intended to go for ionic2. So I install :

```
npm install -g cordova
npm install -g ionic@beta
```

When I recognize that ionic2 doesn't support blackberry, I want to downgrade to ionic1 version. I don't know which is the latest version of ionic1. So I tried the following:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm uninstall -g ionic

npm install -g cordova ionic
npm ionic -v
```

After re-installing, the version of ionic is still: 2.0.0-beta.33

Even I downgrade ionic to version 1.4.0, it is still: 2.0.0-beta.33

```
npm install -g ionic@1.4.0
```

Could you help? Thanks

Comment: You can still create Ionic 1 projects from the ionic@beta CLI so there shouldn't be a problem for you

Comment: Indeed, yes. Thanks.

Comment: @chipbk10    now i am facing this issue. I have `ionic version 3.0.0`. Now i have the old ionic 1 project. but when i build in android like `ionic build android` it showing syntax changed to ` cordova ionic build android`. and not able to run `npm install` in my `ionic 1` project... Now how can i create a new `ionic 1` project with the last version of ionic 1.. please tell me